# Docker returning same kernel version for 10.04 and 10.10

Tags: docker

I'm probably misunderstanding something.  Shouldn't the ubuntu:12.10 kernel be higher than the ubuntu:12.04 one?

`$ sudo docker run ubuntu:12.04 /bin/uname -a

Linux cb466a57b8c2 3.2.0-23-generic #36-Ubuntu SMP Tue Apr 10 20:39:51 UTC 2012 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux`

`$ sudo docker run ubuntu:12.10 /bin/uname -a

Linux 62aadcf4e486 3.2.0-23-generic #36-Ubuntu SMP Tue Apr 10 20:39:51 UTC 2012 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux`

Here's the version info:

`$ sudo docker version

Client version: 0.5.3

Server version: 0.5.3

Go version: go1.1`

Comment: You might want to upgrade your docker. doc for upgrade to docker v0.6: http://docs.docker.io/en/latest/installation/ubuntulinux/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The kernel version is not linked to the image.

No matter what version or even what distribution you run, you will always run with the host's kernel.

That's one of the main differences with VMs, docker does all the isolation at the kernel level. There is no kernel emulation.

If you need to tests different kernels, then you need to use virtualization like KVM/qemu or Virtualbox.